# How to make math text thick globally besides \mathversion{bold}

Tags: beamer, math-mode

I'm making slides using the `beamer` package for a math course aiming at a large audience, but the default math  text too slim for a big classroom. When I include `\mathversion{bold}`, the math text become too thick (unfortunately ugly).  Is there any other approach to control the math text globally?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%========================
\begin{document}
%==========
% \mathversion{bold}
   \begin{frame}
      \frametitle{Derivative}
       Proof sketch 
     \begin{align*}
         &\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{u(x+h)v(x+h)-u(x)v(x)}{h}\\
        =&\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{u(x+h)v(x+h){-u(x)v(x+h)+u(x)v(x+h)}-  u(x)v(x)}{h}\\
        =&\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{{[u(x+h)-u(x)]}v(x+h)+u(x){[v(x+h)-v(x)]}}{h}\\
        =&\lim_{h\to 0}{\frac{[u(x+h)-u(x)]}{h}}\cdot \lim_{h\to 0}v(x+h) +u(x)\cdot\lim_{h\to 0}{\frac{[v(x+h)-v(x)]}{h}}\\
        =&{ u^{\,\prime}(x)}\cdot v(x)+u(x)\cdot { v^{\,\prime}(x)}
    \end{align*}
 \end{frame}
%=============
\end{document}
```

Comment: Change font? We have no idea what code you are using, so it is pretty much impossible to say anything useful.

Comment: sorry for not inculding the code

Answer (score 5):

You can embolden everything by redrawing the outlines of all the characters with a thicker line.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Hello World!}
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
  \[ F(x) = \int f(x) \;\mathrm{d}x \]
\end{frame}

\pdfliteral direct{2 Tr 0.05 w}

\begin{frame}{Hello World!}
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
  \[ F(x) = \int f(x) \;\mathrm{d}x \]
\end{frame}

\pdfliteral direct{0 Tr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, it looks much better now! But how control only the math environment without changing the normal text?  I mean,  globally changing the math enviroment once for all.

Comment: @C.Davide That is very tricky.  The problem is that LaTeX defines hooks to do stuff when entering math mode (`\everymath`, `\everydisplay`) but no hooks to do stuff when *exiting* math mode.  That means we could set the boldness, but never unset it again.  Also I think, if you want to increase the font weight, you should do it throughtout math and text.  Otherwise it will look silly.